# Image not fitting correctly

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to fit the image `<img class="img-drawer"...` inside the div `<div class="site-container">`, but for some reason the image gets 1 or 2 pixels top and bottom smaller than it should.

PS: I'm just starting out WebDev, so it's not very tidy. Sorry.

https://codepen.io/ualmeida/pen/jOWYaEm

Edit: the end result should look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbEkH.jpg)

Comment: Your `.site-container` has a `margin` of `23rem`, which seems very excessive. However, it's impossible to know what it *should* look like without you showing the *expected* result in addition to the current situation. The fact that you use `position: absolute` also plays into things; I would recommend you start out with a framework like Bootstrap or React to help you learn about the positioning of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that your margin of 23rem is quite excessive. Your ".img-drawer" has "2px" worth of padding and the height is set to "height: 313px;". Maybe try and add the "height" property to your ".site-container" and set it to something bigger, say "height: 320px;" and see if that helps.